# Need to fetch values from another table that correspond to specific values in my table and add them as a column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One of them has a list of animals (700). Below is what it looks like.

TABLE 1:
Animal | Location

The animals include black cat, white cat, grey cat, black dog etc

The second table has the animal list and its species (There are a total of 75 species).

TABLE 2:
Animal | Species

In this table the animal has black cat, and species as cat. Similarly, animal as white cat, species as cat.

Now I need to insert a column to Table 1 that maps the animal with its species from Table 2. It is just like a vlookup function we do in excel. Please note that I want an additional COLUMN added to Table 1, not a query.

Comment: ' I want an additional COLUMN added to Table 1, not a query.' - that's excel thinking and not something you you should do in a relational db  - if you must then you would have to ALTER table 1 to add the column and UPDATE to add the species.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I need to know how to map the two. I can generate a query that joins the two using JOIN. I need to attach it as a column. Can you help?

Comment: Please publish your alter table and query and review Multiple-table syntax: here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: I am not sure how UPDATE will work. Both tables have different number of rows. I am unsure how I will map them. Here is what I have done but this doesn't seem to work.

INSERT INTO Table1(Species)

SELECT 
 Species
FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.animalr = t2.animal

Comment: An INSERT adds rows not columns ,an UPDATE updates columns and is your only option here.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. So how will I map the species from the other table to the new column? Do I use JOIN here?